# Django: cleaned_data for special characters and punctuation marks

Tags: python, django, django-forms, python-re

I want to validate the Name field in my form.

Now I have in my `forms.py`:

```
 def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if re.search(r'\d', name):
            raise ValidationError('The name must not have numbers')
        if re.search(r'\s', name):
            raise ValidationError('The name must not have spaces')
        return name
```

But I also want to create validation for special characters and punctuation marks.

I have tried some ways with `[[:punct:]]`, but this returns an error to me, and I guess that this doesn't work with Python or another way of using it is needed.

Is there any way to do this, I need help.

Comment: What do you consier "special characters"?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem special symbols ., +, *, ?, ^, $, (, ), [, ], {, }, |, \ etc

Comment: Diacritics as well? Non-printable characters? Wingdings, emojis, ...? The problem is that you should be specific what you want to exclude.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think Diacritics, Non-printable characters, Wingdings, emojis - no need. Only what the user will be able to enter from the keyboard instead of his name or in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it manually by making a list of special characters and punctuation marks and iterating each character of `name` field, as shown in the example here:

```
def clean_name(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data['name']
    special_puncs = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '&', '*', '(', ')'] # you can also include more chars and puncs
    for i in name:
        if i in special_puncs:
            raise ValidationError(
                'Name cannot contain special chars and punctuations.')

    if re.search(r'\d', name):
        raise ValidationError('The name must not have numbers')
    if re.search(r'\s', name):
        raise ValidationError('The name must not have spaces')
    return name
```